# Controlling JRebel package scope

Tags: classloader, wildfly, jprofiler, jrebel

I am trying to speed up execution of code being debugged with JRebel. In particular, I notice that framework code is slow. I am wondering whether I can tell JRebel to ignore certain packages, in much the same way that we can setup JProfiler to ignore certain packages and patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most definitely can.

- Use a system property (or add to *jrebel.properties*) meant just for that purpose. More information at [JRebel agent properties](https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/misc/agentsettings.html#agent-properties).

  ```
  -Drebel.exclude_packages=PACKAGE1,PACKAGE2,...
  ```
- Specify the excluded packages in *rebel.xml* using Ant-styled patterns. More information at [rebel.xml configuration](https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/advanced-config.html#exclude).

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://update.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/rebel-2_1.xsd">
    <classpath>
      <dir name="/path/to/module/build/directory/root">
        <exclude name="com/yourapp/package1/internal/**"/>
      </dir>
    </classpath>
  </application>
  ```

---

Both ways work similarly but since the second one enables to customize each module inividually it is generally preferred.